# Embedded YouTube video is not working on asp.net MVC/Angular app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, video, youtube

I have tried to embed the video as shown below on my asp.net mvc app.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 center " data-animation="bounceInRight" data-delay="300">
     <iframe width="170" height="128" ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=1aDLYFBuWc8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%; margin:0 auto; display:block;"></iframe>
</div>
```

But when I tried to play, it shows below error.

[image]

There is no `console window` errors.When I tried to get the url by right clicking the above video then it shows this : `https://youtu.be/undefined`

But when I embeded below kind of url then it works fine.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o
```

Could you tell me how to sort out this issue ? Thanks in advance.

**Answer :** 
I think I can avoid this issue if I use the `Video_Id` as @Jossef Harush mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `ng-src` in redundant

Since you don't dynamically set the video url in your example. no need to use `ng-src`

- `ng-src`  - http://plnkr.co/edit/HfJRVtt1Qga5UgyU242u?p=preview
- `src` - http://plnkr.co/edit/LROnn8jHak1P8Hk4bR7e?p=preview

## YouTube Embed URL is incorrect

from they're [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> ### Embed a player using an  tag
>
> Define an  tag in your application in which the src URL
>   specifies the content that the player will load as well as any other
>   player parameters you want to set. The  tag's height and width
>   parameters specify the dimensions of the player.
>
> If you create the  element yourself (rather than using the
>   IFrame Player API to create it), you can append player parameters
>   directly to the end of the URL. The URL has the following format:
>
> `http://www.youtube.com/embed/`**VIDEO_ID**

**use** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o`
 instead of <del>`https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=1aDLYFBuWc8`</del>

**[Sample on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OIpWJurtjTD6DKuoGHyx?p=preview)**

Comment: Actually this is just a sample.I need to add the series of videos into app's video gallery.So could you tell me how to get the video_id when user enters different types of you tube video's urls (`JavaScript`)?

Comment: @Sampath, iv'e made an example - http://plnkr.co/edit/OIpWJurtjTD6DKuoGHyx?p=preview
simply copy & paste the url and click add

Answer (score 0):

go to the wanted Youtube video and click on Share then you will get the option for a code snippet which you can embed into your code.

This is the default from yt

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="Link here" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad url and you can't use ng-src try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 center " data-animation="bounceInRight" data-delay="300">
     <iframe width="170" height="128" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1aDLYFBuWc8?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="max-width:100%; margin:0 auto; display:block;"></iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6w3ao4ft/

Comment: What do you mean by can't use `ng-src` ?

Comment: That you have to use `src` instead `ng-src` in this contest